# Memory build using images on a timer

Tags: javascript

I have an asp.net web page.

I have a javascript timer.

I have an html img tag.

I am updating the image src within the timer.

The img src is set to an ashx handler.

after a while, in Task manager, the memory for my browser shoots up.

I imagine it because I am not disposing of an image properly.

When i do dispose of the image and update it with the new one I get a flickering.

How can i dispose my bitmaps properly without causing any flcikering?

Thanks,

my code:

Thi is in live.ashx

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Live : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(Shared.CurrentFrameInBytes);
    }
    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the javscript in my asp.net markup page:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <img alt="" src="Portal/Live/Current.jpg" id="imgLive" name="imgLive" />
    </div>
    <div id="divImageCache1" style="width: 352px; height: 288px; display: none;">
        <img alt="" src="" id="imgCached" />
    </div>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="Play();"/>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var timer2, intervalMS = 100

    function Play() {
        if (timer2) window.clearTimeout(timer2);
        swapImages();
    }

    function setImageSrc(src) {
        //imgLive.src = null; - if I uncomment this I get flickering    
        imgLive.src = src;
        timer2 = window.setTimeout(swapImages, intervalMS);
    }

    function swapImages() {
        var imgCached = new Image();
        imgCached.onload = function () {
            setImageSrc(imgCached.src);
        };
        imgCached.onerror = function () {
            //setImageSrc("Error.jpg");
        };
        imgCached.src = null;
        imgCached.src = 'http://aurl/Cloud/Live.ashx'; 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, someone called @Yoshi gave the right answer but I cannot mark it as correct because he deleted it. If you re-post will award you with a tick :)

Comment: I undeleted my answer. I removed it at first, as I wasn't sure if it was gonna help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest reusing the image instead of constantly creating new a one, e.g.:

```
var Play = function () {
  var
    timeout,
    delay = 100,
    live = document.getElementById('imgLive'),
    cache = new Image();

  cache.addEventListener('load', function () {
    live.src = this.src;
  }, false);

  return function Play() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    (function loop() {
      cache.src = null;
      cache.src = 'http://www.informedmotion.co.uk/Cloud/Live.ashx';

      timeout = setTimeout(loop, delay);
    })();
  };
}();
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/alArahu/1/